# Go to a route and pass props in event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify autocomplete search and when an item from that is selected, I want to go to a specific route and pass props.

Without first passing props, I have attempted to just change current route like so, when a model is selected by v-autocomplete

```
v-on:input="this.window.location.href = '/markets'"
v-on:input="this.$router.push({path: '/markets'})"
```

These give the following errors

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of null"
```

So how do I change route and pass props to the "Markets" component in the event handler?

EDIT:
Passing method instead

Same error for 
`v-on:input="goToMarkets()"`

```
methods: {
    goToMarkets(){ this.window.location.href = '/markets' }
    }
```

`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `this` context is not available in the template. That's why it's telling you `* is not available on undefined`

You will need to create a method and reference that in the template.

the reason `this.window.location` gives you an error is that window is a top level object, and not on `this`. Use `window.location` instead in the method.

Comment: Same error for
`v-on:input="goToMarkets()"`
`goToMarkets(){
      this.window.location.href = '/markets'
    }`

 `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"`

Comment: can you elaborate, adding detail in the question

Comment: Ok removing this worked. But what about passing props to the component on that path?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What props are you trying to pass in the template?

Comment: I misunderstood how passing props to route worked. This is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/60770633/12636797