# Pass object as prop when pushing route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This function is in a component outside router view.

```js
goToMarkets(){
      this.$router.push({path: '/markets', params: {stock: this.model}})
    }
```

But the prop is undefined in the "Markets" component

Router:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/markets',
    name: 'Markets',
    component: Markets,
    props: true
  },]
```

Markets component:

```js
props: {
    stock: Object
  },
```

The prop is undefined in the Markets component even though it's not before it is passed (in the first function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of things happening here.

Firstly, route params form part of the URL and are defined upfront in the route definition.

Given the route definition:

```js
{
  path: '/markets/:myparam',
  name: 'markets',
}
```

then you would transition to it like this:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'markets', params: { myparam: 'foo' } })
```

and the URL would look like:

```
/markets/foo
```

You haven't defined any params for your route, so it won't work.

Secondly, the params must be strings or numbers. You can't pass objects as params. There is just no way to do this; it isn't supported. I think the philosophy here is that the URL alone should contain all router state.

One way to solve this is to pass an ID and then fetch the object from the ID from some shared store (e.g. Vuex).

I don't know what your `stock` model is, but perhaps the param could be just a string like `msft` so the URL is like `/markets/msft`? Can you make it work without needing to pass the full object?

If it's a small object, you can deconstruct the properties of the object into query parameters. But you cannot pass an object instance along with the route transition like you would pass an object as an argument to a function call.

Comment: I assumed I could treat the markets component as a child component and pass props.
It is a small object yeah, with only 3 attributes. I guess I could pass them separately.

Comment: hack -> stringify your object, now you can pass as param

Comment: @the_raging_deaner this solution have an issue , when refresh the page objet prop will be lost

Comment: Any other way to get around this? It doesn't make sense that you load data from the backend in one parent component, then pass the id of the data to its child component only load it again. It would be nice to just pass an entire prop to that route.